# Having Trouble With Fun Optimization Problem

Tags: optimization, contest-math, recreational-mathematics

One of my friends who knows I like math puzzles (but doesn't know that optimization problems are sort-of my weakness), gave me the following problem:

Given that:

2(10a + 13b + 14c + 15d) − ((a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2)/3) = 2020,

what is the maximum possible value of a + b + c + d.

I don't really know where to begin on this problem. I tried contacting the friend for help/a hint a couple times last week, but she still hasn't gotten back to me. I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to solve this problem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, please edit the question to make clear where the '/3' is.

Comment: Hmm, a friend? ${}{}$

Comment: this is pretty easy to solve via the Lagrangian

Comment: By the Tangent Line method we can get the following answer: $156+10\sqrt6$, which is very ugly. @Bella G. Check please the given.

Comment: @VinayakSuresh, thanks, I just edited it!

Comment: @copper.hat Yes, a friend, why? I do have friends, if that is the question. ;)

Comment: @LinAlg, thanks for your input! I'm not familiar with the Langragian. Can you please help me understand what that is? Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg, thanks! I'm not familiar with the Tangent Line method, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Its like asking the doctor, emm, my friend has this itch...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** What you are given is equivalent to

$$ ( a - 30)^2 + (b-39)^2 + (c-42)^2 + (d-45)^2 = 150 .$$

From there, what is the maximum value of $ ( a - 30) + (b-39) + (c-42) + (d-45)$?
Hence, conclude that the answer is $156 + 10 \sqrt{6} $.

Comment: Bravo! Very nice!

Comment: Thanks! Is there a good method for finding maximums when you have multiple variables in an equation?

Comment: Never mind! Got it, thanks!

Comment: @BellaG. There are multiple methods, so you will have to build up your bank of tools. For quadratic forms (of which this is one), one of the common approaches is to simplify the constraint into "standard form" (if not already done so), and transform the expression accordingly. That is the approach that I took here. (Complicated way of describing what should be rather intuitive)